# Reduce size of node_modules folder by soft linking

Tags: node.js, npm

I have noticed running `find node_modules -path '*/lodash'`
that a lot of packages includes lodash, and by looking on the package.json it's even the exact same version.

Because lodash it's heavy (4.5MB), if all of them share the exact same memory allocation (by using a symbolic link), I should be able to reduce the size of the node_modules folder by at least 20MB, only by linking lodash modules together.

A good script should be able to find more packages rather than simply lodash, and probably save a lot more space.

Does anyone know a script/module that is able to do that?
Or I should implement it myself?

Comment: What version of NPM are you using? Run `npm -v`. If you're using a version lower than NPM 3, you should upgrade - massive improvements to package deduping were made in that release.

Comment: I'm using npm 4.2.0 with node 7.9.0

Comment: Ah, okay. Rules one thing out, at least :) Have you tried running `npm dedupe`?

Comment: Tried now, no results, the size of the node_modules it's the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this custom script:

```
import json
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint
import os
import subprocess

allPackages = subprocess.check_output("find node_modules/ -name 'package.json'", shell=True).splitlines()

# Collect all modules
allModules = {}
for filePath in allPackages:
    with open(filePath.strip()) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        packageKey = data['name'] + data['version']
        if packageKey not in allModules:
            allModules[packageKey] = list()
        allModules[packageKey].append(os.path.dirname(filePath))

# Remove not duplicated ones
for packageKey, paths in allModules.items():
    if (len(paths) > 1):
        original = allModules[packageKey].pop()
        for module in allModules[packageKey]:
            originalRelativeToModule = os.path.relpath(original,os.path.dirname(module))
            print('delete folder ', module, 'and symlink to ', originalRelativeToModule)
            print(subprocess.check_call(["rm","-rf",module]))
            print(subprocess.check_call(["ln","-s",originalRelativeToModule,module]))
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure you didn't examine if they have the same version, right?
In each npm package, in package.json file there is specific version or '*'. 
I didn't check, but I'm sure it is properly handeled by npm.

Just [quick google result](https://www.npmjs.com/package/symlink) - this might help you to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I checked, are the exact same version (5 out of 7 of them are version "4.17.4"). And I checked if they were symlinks because was the first thing I think that npm should handle that

Comment: It's very strange, they shouldn't do that assuming how require works...

Comment: I tried symlink, and doesn't work inside the node_modules folder, can work if multiple repos are available

Answer (score 0):

Use `pnpm` instead of `npm`. This is complete solution for reduce `node_modules` space (by sharing modules from all projects for one os user).

Read more:
https://pnpm.io